# Theta Methods for Nonlinear PDE

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

Does anyone know of any advanced texts in numerical analysis that discuss the stability of theta schemes for nonlinear hyperbolic pdes?

Comment: The stability analysis for nonlinear hyperbolic pdes is already quite rarely described (except maybe for the Godunov scheme and related methods). There is little chance that such and advanced numerical analysis text can be found.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! I was afraid that was indeed the case but hoped that I had overlooked something during my research.